# Linux shell script delete/restore/trash

Tags: shell

TIA in advance for any help. This is coursework so further reading is always appreciated!

Basically I have to write 3 scripts in bash. One to 'delete' a file to a directory of my creation (~/rubbish). Another to restore it if needs be and a third to permanently delete it.

I'm kinda stuck on my trash script. It doesn't seem to be actually deleting anything as ls shows all the files still there. I am also having trouble with the flag (-a) that I have added for the user to trash all at once, IF not then it should ask confirmation for each file found.

Here's where I am just now...

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "-a" ] 
then
cd ~/rubbish
rm ~/rubbish
mkdir ~/rubbish
echo "All files have been deleted"
else
cd ~/rubbish
ls > rubbish
for line in 'cat rubbish'
do
echo "Do you want to delete?" $line
echo "Y/N"
read ans
case "ans" in
Y|y ) rm $line;;
N|n ) " ";;
esac
done
fi
```

As I said, it doesn't see -a , and it skips the first branch and runs through the second seemingly fine, but when I ls ~/rubbish all the files are still there.

*EDIT* Thanks for the help guys! Sputnik, erm couldn't really see what you had changed in your comment other than adding semi colons? And inductiveLoad, your answer was ace, but I couldn't find a way to work it properly, lost patience and went uber basic. Like so....

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "-a" ] ;
then 
cd ~/rubbish;
rm ~/rubbish/*;
echo "All files have been deleted";
else
  rm -i ~/rubbish/* ;
fi
```

Comment: Try doing this `#!/bin/bash;if [ "$1" = "-a" ] ;then;cd ~/rubbish;rm ~/rubbish;mkdir ~/rubbish;echo "All files have been deleted";else;cd ~/rubbish;ls > rubbish;for line in 'cat rubbish';do;echo "Do you want to delete?" $line;echo "Y/N";read ans;case "ans" in;Y|y ) rm $line;;;N|n ) " ";;;esac;done;fi`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `getopts` to parse options, as it allows much more flexibility, any number of arbitrarily ordered arguments, options with data (as opposed to a flag - see the `-d` option below) and also prints help if you give bad options.

```
usage()
{
cat <<EOF
usage: $0 options

This script deletes/restores/trashes files.

OPTIONS:
    -h  Show this message
    -a  Trash it all!
    -d  Rubbish directory
EOF
}

trashAll=false
rubbishDir="~/rubbish"

while getopts "ad:" OPTION; 
do
  case "$OPTION"
  in
        h)  usage
            exit 1;;
        a)  trashAll=true;;
        d)  rubbishDir=${OPTARG};;
        ?)  usage
            exit 1;;
    esac
done

if $trashAll
then
    #trash it all
    echo "Trashing all in ${rubbishDir}!"
fi
```

Comment: +1 Generally for homework questions, we just provide some guidance, not the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Sputnik, erm couldn't really see what you had changed in your comment other than adding semi colons? And inductiveLoad, your answer was ace, but I couldn't find a way to work it properly, lost patience and went uber basic.